# NetLogo 3D: Transparent Patches

Tags: 3d, transparent, patch, netlogo

I am trying to use NetLogo 3D, but when I click "setup", I can't see the turtles through the 3D patches. If I go to settings and make the zcor 0, I can see my turtles. So, I know that my code works. Is there any way that I can make the patches transparent so that I can see through them. I've done some searching, and it looks like there is no way to do it. But, I wanted to see if any of you knew any different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the [NetLogo programming guide on colors](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/programming.html#colors), specifically the section on RGB and RGBA Colors. In short, you can specify colors using a list of 3 or 4 numbers (all from 0 to 255). The first is the amount of red, the second the amount of green, the third the amount of blue, and the fourth (if present) is how opaque the color should be. The lower this last number is, the more transparent the color will be. So `set pcolor [255 0 0 192]` will make a patch red and mostly opaque, whereas `set pcolor [255 0 0 64]` will make the patch quite see-through.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! When I initially saw the programming guide, I was thinking that the transparency was only for turtles! Thank you so much!